# How to execute a set of statements in child process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, shell

I want to execute a set of statements which is a combination of shell and python code in python script in a child process. I am using subprocess.call() method but it only takes one shell command as input. I want to execute some python code after the shell command in the child process and exit the child process once shell+python code has finished execution.

```
command = "./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg yolov3-tiny.weights {0}".format(latest_subdir)
proc = subprocess.Popen([command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
with open(result_file, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(out)
os.system('mv {0} {1}'.format(latest_subdir,processed_dir))
s3_util.upload_results([result_file])
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: There is no problem and it executes fine. I want to execute ALL these statements in a child process. Not just './darknet', but also 'mv' and s3_util.upload_results()

Comment: So basically you want to write a shell script with no Python code at all?

Comment: No, I want that the given statements are executed in a child process sequentially and the process finishes after executing the last line of code

Answer (score 0):

When you send a string to `os.system`, you use the syntax of the system command shell.  For instance, this works just fine on Linux:

```
os.system('ls; wc -l so.py; echo "done"')
```

Separate the commands with semicolons.

Comment: All the commands are not shell, if I were using only shell I would have sent them in one. There's also some python execution and a file write.